# Read from file and display the content using Prolog DCG rule

Tags: prolog, dcg

i am a newbie in prolog, i want to read a file which actually contains CLASS Definition - using Prolog DCG Rule. But i am stuck in between now..

My input text (linessample.txt)

```
class component {
        attributes
          Real V, I, R;
        constraints
          V = I * R;
        constructors component(V1, I1, R1) {
          V = V1; I = I1; R = R1;
        }
}
```

I want to read the above sample text using DCG Rule in prolog... I have written one sample code.. but i am not getting the first word "class" in the output

Code

```
    :- use_module(library(pio)).
    %classrule(Z) -->class,letter(X),letters(L),{name(Z,[X|L])}.
    classrule(Z) -->"class ",classname(X),"{",{name(Z,X)}.
    classname([X|L])-->letter(X),letters(L).
    letters([X|L])-->letter(X),!,letters(L).
    class-->"class".
    letters([])-->[].
    letter(X)-->[X], {alpha(X)}.
    alpha(X) :- X > 64, X < 91.
    alpha(X) :- X > 96, X < 123.
```

how to run this

```
    phrase_from_file(classrule(Z),'linesample.txt').
```

Comment: Can you help me to read the sentence "class Component{". I tried my best.But i can't get the solution

Answer (score 3):

There are two main problems with your program:
  1. You do not allow for a space to occur between classname/1 and "{". Since in practice multiple spaces (and horizontal tabs) may occur here, I have used `whites//0` from library `dcg/basics`.
  2. `phrase_from_file/2` tries to parse the entire input document, whereas your grammar only covers the first line (i.e., the class name). This is solved by skipping the rest of the file. I use `'...'//0` and then `eos//0` for this.

Then there are some minor things:
  1. Clauses of `letters//1` are not placed consecutively in the code file. I have relocated one clause but you can also add the declarations `:- discontiguous(letters//1).` at the top of your program.
  2. I have used `code_type/2` to check for alphabetic characters.

The resultant code, updated after useful comments from mat:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).
:- use_module(library(pio)).

classrule(Z) -->
  "class",
  whites,
  classname(X),
  whites,
  "{",
  {name(Z,X)},
  ... .

classname([H|T])-->
  letter(H),
  letters(T).

letters([H|T])-->
  letter(H), !,
  letters(T).
letters([])--> [].

letter(X)-->
  [X],
  {code_type(X, alpha)}.

... --> [].
... -->
  [_],
  ... .
```

Example of use:

```
?- phrase_from_file(classrule(X), 'linesample.txt').
X = component
```

Comment: Great answer, +1. There's no need to put `...` in single quotes, since it is already an atom. `eos//0` is also not needed here, since `phrase_from_file/2` only succeeds if the whole list is described by the DCG body.

Comment: @mat You're right, one has to put a space in between `...` and `.` but then it works! I've updated my answer accordingly.