# extract a class definition from a file using dcg in prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

Can any one help me to generate a prolog grammar of a simple class definition.
This is a sample dcg rule i have written.

```
   :- use_module(library(pio)).
   %classrule(Z) -->class,letter(X),letters(L),{name(Z,[X|L])}.
   classrule(Z) -->"class ",classname(X),"{",{name(Z,X)}.
   classname([X|L])-->letter(X),letters(L).
   letters([X|L])-->letter(X),!,letters(L).
   class-->"class".
   letters([])-->[].
   letter(X)-->[X], {alpha(X)}.
   alpha(X) :- X > 64, X < 91.
   alpha(X) :- X > 96, X < 123.
```

input:

```html
class component {
        attributes
          Real V, I, R;
        constraints
          V = I * R;
        constructors component(V1, I1, R1) {
          V = V1; I = I1; R = R1;
        }
}
```

Comment: How is this question different from a [recent question you posted in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225602/read-from-file-and-display-the-content-using-prolog-dcg-rule)?

Comment: @WouterBeek provided an excellent answer to this question in the link he provided. What is wrong with it? Do you have additional issues? If so, you need to ask clearly.